# Render layer offscreen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

How can I create/prepare a CALayer offscreen, so that when the page is displayed, then all it has to do is to display the prepared layer?

Answer (score 3):

Render your content into an CGBitmapContext, pull a CGImageRef off of that and set that as the contents of the CALayer. Take a look at [Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE) for example code for most of this.

But if your real problem is that your `drawInContext:` is too slow, you should first look at breaking that up so that you pre-calculate everything when the data changes and only do drawing in `drawInContext:`. This is generally the better approach. Don't pre-render the layer itself; pre-calculate everything you need to render the layer quickly. But for very complicated drawing, the CGImageRef approach is useful.